# Focus event on jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to handle focus event on input element with attached Datepicker to save original value.

Unfortunately it seems that any click on popup elements like next month button also generates focus events on input. They look exactly like real focus events from input.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwisnicki/Lb5L2/4/).

```
<input id="dt" type="text"></input>
```

and

```
$("#dt")
.datepicker()
.on('focus blur', function(e) {
    console.warn("!%s", e.type, this, arguments[0], event);
});
```

How can I handle only real focus events while ignoring the rest ?

Comment: `e.isTrigger` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/Lb5L2/5/

Comment: What's the difference between "real" and "fake" focus events? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Zhihao real events are generated by browser (mouse) while fake events are synthesized by jquery

Comment: @A.Wolff while e.isTrigger does the trick, it's not a public API.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki and what about `e.originalEvent`???

Comment: It's present on all events and looks real.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki shouldn't for focus event but issue is for blur event because plugin doesn't trigger this event in any case, it is fired because of browser behaviour when setting focus on other element, here datepicker ones

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb5L2/6/  Works for focus but cannot for blur

Comment: @A.Wolff: 'user interaction' is never logged

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki oh ya, it isn't on FF

Comment: Looks like related to jQuery UI 1.10.3 regarding issue on FF: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb5L2/8/  But anyway, won't handle blur case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you can keep some state in your event handler. When you get a focus event, set a `datePickerOpened` flag to true and only do your thing when that flag was false when the event was received. Then, set `datePickerOpened` to false when you get the blur event.

Comment: Unfortunately there are fake blur events as well.